# What is the effect of using dashes between each word in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, hyphenation, dashes

In *The Bluest Eye*, there is a quote:

> Grown people frowned and fussed: 'You-don’t-know- how-to-take-care-of-nothing. I-never-had-a-baby-doll-in-my-whole-life-and-used-to-cry-my-eyes-out-for-them. Now-you-got-one-a-beautiful-one-and-you-tear-it-up-what’s-the-matter-with-you?'

When reading, I was a bit confused and curious as to Morrison's choice of dashing between each word. Could someone, perhaps, elaborate on this choice?

In context, the quote is being said by African-American adults towards an African-American little girl, with the location being Ohio.

Comment: In that extended-use context looks suggestive of conveying the sentiment, i.e. perceived attitude of adults by the child rather than direct quotations by them (though string of hyphenated words could also be seen maybe as archetypal sayings to the child by them in a similar vein as perceived by her, of a theme there seeming to be "to chalk-it-up, you have it better than we did").   {{@Mods: I hope this comment is not out of line. If it is, delete it and message received. I'm not confident with enough time at this point to research and type a full Answer response, ergo this pointed comment.}}

Comment: We often hyphenate things that are said by others so often they seem to be automatic robotic expressions (that we are tired of hearing) Here's my mother with her _why-don't-you-get-a-job-you-fat-jerk?_

Comment: We group normally unrelated words with hyphens to combine them conceptually into a single concept, whether noun or adjective, as M. Harvey notes. This can be jocular or, as in philosophy, more serious. Perhaps a duplicate of [several](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=hyphenated+words+as+adjectives) questions.

Comment: This enters the realm of subjective interpretation of literature. But I looked up the quote and found that the context is that the author has surgically dismembered a doll, and the lines following the quote are "How strong was their outrage. Tears threatened to erase the aloofness of their authority." Hyphenization can also convey rapidity; maybe in context these lines are blurted in an emotional rush. (Oddly, if they were em dashes it might have the opposite effect.)

Comment: The device functions like quotation marks; it holds the relevant words together: "You don’t know how to take care of nothing." But it suggests mimicry rather than simply reporting. In other words, it injects the quoter's feelings into the quote.